# How to get the second element in the list

Tags: c#

I have question how can I get second value (next value) of unixDate? How could I achieve this??

getData window:

```
    public static List<Tuple<string, string>> euDataDaily(string url)
    {
        var aTuple = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { };
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString(url);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        string conditionCode="";
        string unixDate = "";
        string dayTemp="";

        foreach (var result in o["daily"])
            {
            unixDate = (string)result["dt"];
            string day = unixDate;

            if (unixDate.Equals(day))
                {
                    dayTemp = (string)result["temp"]["day"];
                }
                if (unixDate.Equals(day))
                {
                    foreach (var res in result["weather"])
                    {
                        conditionCode = (string)res["description"];
                    }                  
                }                     
            }
            aTuple.Add(Tuple.Create(dayTemp, conditionCode));           
        return aTuple;
    }
```

EDIT: I need to get second "dt" value.

Data:

```
{"lat":56.94,"lon":24.1,"timezone":"Europe/Riga","timezone_offset":10800,"daily":[{"dt":1617703200,"sunrise":1617680352,"sunset":1617729143,"temp":{"day":6,"min":-1.1,"max":7.55,"night":1.3,"eve":5.46,"morn":-1.1},"feels_like":{"day":2.15,"night":-6.52,"eve":1.56,"morn":-6.52},"pressure":993,"humidity":61,"dew_point":-0.83,"wind_speed":6.05,"wind_deg":241,"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":75,"pop":0.58,"snow":0.11,"uvi":2.12},
{"dt":1617789600,"sunrise":1617766591,"sunset":1617815670,"temp":{"day":6.78,"min":-0.52,"max":7.42,"night":1.41,"eve":6.13,"morn":-0.52},"feels_like":{"day":3.71,"night":-4.96,"eve":3.57,"morn":-4.96},"pressure":1001,"humidity":40,"dew_point":-5.88,"wind_speed":4.67,"wind_deg":216,"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":15,"pop":0.62,"snow":0.22,"uvi":2.03},{"dt":1617876000,"sunrise":1617852830,"sunset":1617902197,"temp":{"day":4.38,"min":-0.44,"max":5.07,"night":1.3,"eve":4.02,"morn":0.62},"feels_like":{"day":-0.01,"night":-2.81,"eve":0.96,"morn":-2.81},"pressure":1009,"humidity":53,"dew_point":-4.45,"wind_speed":6.28,"wind_deg":323,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":77,"pop":0.2,"uvi":2.27},
{"dt":1617962400,"sunrise":1617939069,"sunset":1617988724,"temp":{"day":6.12,"min":0.14,"max":7.58,"night":5.43,"eve":7.04,"morn":0.3},"feels_like":{"day":2.03,"night":-4.37,"eve":3.1,"morn":-4.37},"pressure":1015,"humidity":55,"dew_point":-2.05,"wind_speed":6.78,"wind_deg":207,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":78,"pop":0.17,"uvi":2.38},{"dt":1618048800,"sunrise":1618025309,"sunset":1618075252,"temp":{"day":6.91,"min":4.2,"max":8.85,"night":5.84,"eve":8.85,"morn":4.2},"feels_like":{"day":4.17,"night":0.35,"eve":6.67,"morn":0.35},"pressure":1014,"humidity":74,"dew_point":2.54,"wind_speed":4.07,"wind_deg":216,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0.39,"rain":0.49,"uvi":2.56},{"dt":1618135200,"sunrise":1618111550,"sunset":1618161779,"temp":{"day":4.54,"min":4.48,"max":5.66,"night":5.14,"eve":5.09,"morn":5.29},"feels_like":{"day":2.15,"night":5.29,"eve":2.3,"morn":5.29},"pressure":1017,"humidity":96,"dew_point":4,"wind_speed":2.74,"wind_deg":358,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":1,"rain":10.84,"uvi":3},
    {"dt":1618221600,"sunrise":1618197791,"sunset":1618248307,"temp":{"day":10.63,"min":4.78,"max":11.88,"night":4.78,"eve":7.64,"morn":7.95},"feels_like":{"day":9.99,"night":5.74,"eve":4.6,"morn":5.74},"pressure":1017,"humidity":86,"dew_point":8.42,"wind_speed":3.31,"wind_deg":190,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0.98,"rain":4.16,"uvi":3},
{"dt":1618308000,"sunrise":1618284033,"sunset":1618334834,"temp":{"day":5.87,"min":2.34,"max":7.02,"night":3.39,"eve":5.9,"morn":2.34},"feels_like":{"day":2.87,"night":-2.08,"eve":3.91,"morn":-2.08},"pressure":1027,"humidity":55,"dew_point":-2.38,"wind_speed":4.11,"wind_deg":268,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":90,"pop":0.2,"rain":0.11,"uvi":3}]}
```

Thanks for response.

Comment: `list.Skip(1).Take(1)`, `list.ElementAt(1)` or about 10 other ways to achieve what you want to do :)

Comment: off topic: I am very confused about this line: `string day = unixDate;` why would you afterwards compare the equality of the 2 variables: `if (unixDate.Equals(day))` how can they not be equal?

Comment: `unixDate` is a `string`. It´s unclear what you mean by "the next value of unixDate", as that term does not exist in a string. Could you please provide some sample-data that shows what exactly you need?

Comment: I provide some data, I need second "dt" value from it, and I confused how to get it.

Comment: From that JSON it´s pretty hard to see what tag you´re interested in. Could you format the JSON appropriately? Apart from this, what does `(string) result["dt"]` return on the second iteration?

Comment: JSON data link: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=59.43&lon=24.75&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=e4ef2ac494977d735811075476bcc0bf

Comment: list[1] can also get the second item in a list